# Why would Chrome not display a padlock icon at all on an SSL site?

Tags: tls, chrome

I have an internal website running on SSL, but when going through it in Chrome, I don't get a padlock icon at all:

[image]

However, clicking it does show that the site is encrypted. There are a bunch of obvious issues - our internal CA doesn't have public audit reports and it's using old TLS, but the weird thing is that I have another server with a similar setup and there the green padlock icon shows up just fine.

I've seen troubleshooting for cases where there's a grey padlock and for cases where EV doesn't work, but neither is the case here - there is no padlock at all. I've used other browsers and tools like OpenSSL and curl and they all tell me SSL is just fine.

Before I assume this is a bug in Chrome, I wonder if there is a rule that I'm overlooking that makes Chrome behave this way intentionally?

[image]

Comment: 3rd hit from search query: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/security/ssl-lock-display

Comment: @schroeder That shows a case where Chrome shows a grey padlock with a yellow triangle. I have found a ton of links on how to troubleshoot those. The link does not show the case where Chrome does not display a padlock _at all_ and where SSL seems to be working perfectly fine (no mixed resources).

Comment: Compare the ciphersuite used.

Comment: @Ángel They are identical - AES_128_CBC, SHA1, RSA.

Comment: @MichaelStum But doesn't your second screenshot show a grey lock with a yellow triangle, and list some reasons for that icon?

Comment: @schroeder But the URL bar doesn't - that's the thing I'm trying to troubleshoot. Another internal website shows a green padlock in the URL bar, even though it shows the same warning about public audit records in the details.

Comment: "Your connection to ... is encrypted with obsolete cryptography" - there you go?

Comment: @immibis That would cause a different icon (grey padlock/yellow triangle). See Rob W's answer below.

Comment: @MichaelStum That is the *same* reason as Rob W's answer.

Comment: "The site is using outdated security settings that may prevent future versions of Chrome from being able to safely access it. [...] Your connection to [...] is encrypted with Obsolete cryptography." Seems to me that Chrome's opinion on the security of that connection is pretty clear.

Comment: @immibis The problem is the outdated security _and_ the expiration date. Again: Another site with the same outdated security works and Chrome does _not_ tell me why anywhere. There is no message within Chrome that says "Because the cert expires after 2016 it's bad", which makes it hard to troubleshoot. If Chrome doesn't want to display the padlock, that's fine, but it should tell me why, and the why is "Because it expires after 2016".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your certificate only contains a sha1 signature, probably with a lifetime past 1 January 2017.

These are deprecated, and Chrome therefore removes the appearance of security. See https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html for more info.

Comment: Wow, that's some really bad user experience. But you're right on the money: The Certificate expires in 2017, while the website that works expires in 2016. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Another reason for it to be "not padlocked" is the 'obsolete cryptography' I suggest you test your "server" with sslabs server test (gives great insight into how secure your setup is, and what to fix.

Comment: For whom is this a bad user experience? For anyone actually using your website, displaying the padlock would give them a (false) sense of security. Proactively encouraging web masters to stop using obsolete ciphers is actually great for Chrome's users.

Comment: How is "This site is using outdated security settings" a bad experience?  It tells you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @JamesRyan No, it doesn't. The problem is the expiration date. It's okay that Chrome complains about the security setting - it's _not_ okay that Chrome allows it on some and not on others without clearly telling why, because that makes troubleshooting it harder and makes it seem like a bug in Chrome. Clear error messages is mandatory to make stuff work, otherwise I'll just assume the browser is broken.

Comment: Your link provided for this answer is a good resource.. the rest of your answer here is somewhat poor.. The padlock is not displaying because Google is in the process of depreciating it.. it is, however, not depreciated or obselete as of yet. Infact, the answer is the expiration date is cause the padlock to not display, if it was set to 3 months.. like google is doing with it's own SHA-1 site certificates.. then the OP would not be seeing this 'issue' of having no Padlock.

Comment: @MichaelStum No the problem is that you need to upgrade all the certs to SHA2 but you will only be forced to for the ones expiring after that date.

Comment: Also, in the link.. and not in your answer.. is another important factor for seeing this security indicator icon: the version of the Browser.

Comment: @MichaelStum you expect useful error messages to be considered a "usability feature"? from what I have seen, usability means obscure the error with the most generic error possible, such as to not scare off the (dumb) user

Comment: @user2813274, ...well done... you would take his argument of this instance and turn it into a generic argument so that you can rant about how being generic is not a feature of usability.

Comment: @BrettCaswell ["it is, however, not depreciated or obselete as of yet."](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83678/why-would-chrome-not-display-a-padlock-icon-at-all-on-an-ssl-site/83682?noredirect=1#comment138556_83682) - wrong, sha1 has already been deprecated since 2011 (see third paragraph of the linked source). And the exact appearance of the non-padlock is indeed version-specific, but the absence of a green padlock is version-independent (i.e. starting from Chrome 39, sha1 certificates are not shown as fully trustworthy any more).

Comment: @RobW the article is incorrect in its assertion.. the document they linked to (https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/Baseline_Requirements_V1.pdf) lists SHA-1 as valid under the conditional statement `SHA-1 MAY be used until SHA-256 is supported widely by browsers used by a substantial portion of relying parties
worldwide.` it was not then.. and is **not** now depreciated. .. but it certainly BEING depreciated.. thus it is **depreciating**

Comment: @BrettCaswell You're citing an old (2012) version of the document. [The current version (1.2.3)](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/BRv1.2.3.pdf) states (section 9.4.2) "Effective 16 January 2015, CAs SHOULD NOT issue Subscriber Certificates utilizing the SHA-1 algorithm with an Expiry Date greater than 1 January 2017 because Application Software Providers are in the process of deprecating and/or removing the SHA-1 algorithm from their software, and they have communicated that CAs and Subscribers using such certificates do so at their own risk." So, sha-1 certs are certainly deprecated.

Comment: @BrettCaswell And before you continue nitpicking: "to deprecate" is defined as "to criticize or express disapproval of (someone or something)" ([source: Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deprecate)). Something that is "in the process of deprecating" *is* "deprecated".

Comment: no.. you are even using the wrong term for the word.. depreciating is the lose of value over time.. depreciated is something that has no value.. this seems to be the major point of confusion here.

Comment: @BrettCaswell Ah, I see where your confusion comes from. I assumed that you simply misspelled the word (that word *is* commonly misspelled), but you just misread. My answer, source and all documents that we've been referring to use "[deprecate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deprecate)", not "[depreciate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/depreciate)". Sha-1 certificates are not loosing value (=depreciated), but they are being phased out (=deprecated).

Comment: ops.. I think you're right Rob.. haha.. sorry

Comment: @MichaelStum, **You aren't the user** of Chrome, your website visitors are. These padlock stuff are not the for website creators, but for the website readers.